# Backbone app POST request to database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, post, backbone.js, model-view-controller

So I have a Backbone app using Rails 4 on the backend. There are two models, Articles and Publications. I have the POST requests nested since I need info that comes back from the publications post to insert into the data object for the the articles post. When I make the POST request to the articles controller I send the the following with the data object: url, publication_id and publication_name. For some reason when I look at the Rails console at the articles that were created I only see that the url and publication_id were populated but not publication_name. Code is pasted here. Any ideas how to get the publication_name to show up?

publications_index.js

```
createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();
    // var that = this;

    this.collection.create(
      { url: feed_url
      },
      { success: function(data){
        var name = data.attributes.name;
        $.post('/articles/force_update', {url: feed_url, publication_id: data.id, publication_name: name}, function(data){
          });
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "publication_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "summary"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.string   "guid"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "publication"
    t.string   "publication_name"
  end
```

article.rb

```
    def self.update_from_feed(feed_url, publication_id, user, publication_name)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    feed.entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :name             => entry.title,
          :summary          => entry.summary,
          :url              => feed_url,
          :published_at     => entry.published,
          :guid             => entry.id,
          :publication_id   => publication_id,
          :user_id          => user.id,
          :publication_name => publication_name
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
  def force_update
    Article.update_from_feed( params[:url], params[:publication_id], current_user, params[:publication_name] )
    render :text => "Success"
  end
```

and

```
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.permit(:name, :publication_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :summary, :url, :published_at, :guid, :publication_name)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to edit the json.builder files to include the other columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the article value, e.g.

```
  def force_update
    Article.update_from_feed( params[:url], params[:publication_id], current_user, params[:publication_name] )
    respond_with(@article)
  end
```

Of course, this supposes that you have your controller set to `respond_to` the json format. In addition, you'd typically want to return a status in addition to the data. But the above should return the data you want...

Comment: Tried it. Still not working and also giving me an error: ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):

Comment: That means your `set_article` function isn't being called (or is being called with an invalid `id`).